# What's the difference between having a library as a dependency in a makefile vs without the dependency symbol

Tags: c++, makefile

I'm quite new to makefiles, and I'm wondering what exactly is the role of the library in this format:

```
app: app.o mylibrary.a
$(LD) -o $@ $(LDFLAGS) app.o mylibrary.a
```

What I usually see would be something like this:

```
app: app.o
$(LD) -o app $(LDFLAGS) $^ mylibrary.a
```

My understanding for this format is that the executable will be made from the `app.o` file, which has a dependency on `mylibrary.a`.

I can't quite understand the difference/meaning of the first version though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where the `$@` is the target is substituted, in the first case that would be `app`.

Although they aren't defined in the question, the `$(LD)` and `$(CFLAGS)` are usually defined as the c-compiler and the flags to use in the compiler.
E.g. something like `CFLAGS = -g -Wall -std=c99 -lstdc++` would be a defined line at the top of the `Makefile`.
I'd usually write these as the first two parts of the command to run for the target.

The `$^` indicates to substitute everything that is listed as a dependency of the target. In the first row the dependencies are `app.o mylibrary.a` whereas in the second it is only `app.o`. These (`$^`, `$@`)are usually used to simplify the writing of make rules.
The choice of whether to use the wildcards-as these are called-is really your own choice. I usually use them because they make it easier to write and maintain.

So to answer your question the main difference is where you *explicitly* need to place the name of the file.

***Additional note on dependencies***
The files in the line where there are dependencies of the target listed are used by `make` to determine which targets need to be rerun. Make does a topological sort of the dependencies and if something changes-based on last touched time of file-the make command will rerun the target if it is within the path of the make target that is being called.

Comment: That helps, thanks. Do you know whether it would make a difference on the first row, if instead of having `app: app.o mylibrary.a` on the first line, we'd simply have `app: app.o` ? The library would remain as a dependency so does it change anything?

Comment: what that would change is whether the library is considered a dependency or not. The dependencies are used by `make` to determine which targets to re-run when the last time a file was touched changes.

Comment: @zPino I added a couple sentences to the answer to clarify what `make` is doing with dependencies. The difference is ultimately whether you want changes to the library to cause the compile command to be re-executed or not. If you include the library file in the dependency list the compile target *would be* re-executed. If the library is omitted, the compile target would not be re-executed on changes to the library file.

Comment: Awesome, thanks!